# SCCM Configuration Baseline Name table

Tags: sccm

Can you please help point me to the right direction as to where I can find the table to map the Name of the Configuration Baseline in SCCM?[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Ceu.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will share my experience for finding specific wmi class or DB tables for Configuration Manager. It may not be the best way, but I find it really helpful for me to get what I want.

**To get WMI Class:**

1. Open CM Admin Console in Debugview Mode. It's easy do by adding **sms:debugview** at the end of console shortcut property target label.
   For example: *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.exe" sms:debugview*
2. After opening console in DebugView mode, you'll find that there is an extra workspace called **Tools**. (You'll find it's a tool to view all WMI Classes on site server)
   [image]
3. In your case, right click the baseline and select '**Show Object Details**' (this is added in debug view mode), you'll notice that you're redirected to Tools workspace and it's showing the baseline WMI Class instance , you'll see all the properties. For example, the name is listed as LocalizedDisplayName. In this case, the baseline WMI Class is SMS_ConfigurationBaselineInfo.

[image]

4. You then can Join any other WMI classes to this one on any property.

**To get SQL DB Views:**
You can use specific keyword and a simple query to find some related views and you'll then be able to find the one you need. keyword is important and  can be for example a key word in above WMI Class name.

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_NAME like '%baseline%'
```

Add

```
and table_type = 'View'
```

in the end if you only want to get only views.

Comment: This helps alot!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's rarely advisable to read anything from the tables directly, and you should instead use the views provided by MS.

Not at work at the moment, so can't check, but I suspect you'll be wanting to look at the DisplayName column in v_LocalizedCIProperties.